# How to order two columns

Tags: mysql, sql-server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IciTP.jpg)
For example, I have a table with columns Last name, First name and Reference number.

The Reference number is sequenced according to the combination of year and id number. something like, (2001-0001) up to (2016-9999).

What I want to happen in my query is that the Refence number will be sorted ascending and the Last name is also sorted ascending.

Given:

```
Reference No. | Last Name | First Name 

2002-0001     | Alban     | Martin
2016-9999     | Edison    | Alex
2001-0001     | Abraham   | Patrick
2002-5555     | Berkley   | Jack
2002-9999     | Clark     | Peter
2001-9999     | Coleman   | James
.....
.....
2001-5555     | Barrack   | Thomas
```

The result will look like;

```
Reference No. | Last Name | First Name 

2001-0001     | Abraham   | Patrick
2001-5555     | Barrack   | Thomas
2001-9999     | Coleman   | James
2002-0001     | Alban     | Martin
2002-5555     | Berkley   | Jack
2002-9999     | Clark     | Peter
.....
.....
2016-9999     | Edison    | Alex
```

I have tried the suggestions from the answers i found in google but it does not answer exactly what I need.

Hope you guys help me
Any comment will be greatly appreciated
Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give all required **column with comma separated** to order by

**LastName ASC /LastName:** Order/Sort column data in ascending order.

**LastName DESC:** Order/Sort column data in descending order

```
DECLARE @tbl1 AS TABLE
(
   RefenceNumber VARCHAR(50),
   LastName VARCHAR(50),
   FirstName VARCHAR(50)
)


INSERT INTO @tbl1 VALUES('2002-0001','Alban','Martin')
INSERT INTO @tbl1 VALUES('2016-9999','Edison','Alex')
INSERT INTO @tbl1 VALUES('2001-0001','Abraham','Patrick')
INSERT INTO @tbl1 VALUES('2002-5555','Berkley','Jack')
INSERT INTO @tbl1 VALUES('2002-9999','Clark','Peter')
INSERT INTO @tbl1 VALUES('2001-9999','Coleman','James')
INSERT INTO @tbl1 VALUES('2001-5555','Barrack','Thomas')

SELECT
    *
FROM @tbl1
Order By RefenceNumber, LastName
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the comment but, only one column is sorted ascending but the other is not.

Comment: ah yeah its great. it worked! thanks a lot. you really helped me on my task.